# Animating Animation node parameters...?

Tags: keyframes, animation-nodes, instances, vector

I am making an animation of atoms in random motion which decrease in speed along with the decreasing temperature.

I made the atoms using animation nodes. Instanced sphere and added vector wiggle to create random motion. Time info node added to animate the evolution which creates the random motion.

Now, I am animating the 'speed' from higher value to lower.

It moves at the speed of 5 first then I keyframed it from 5 to 1 where it acts abnormal and comes to the speed of 1 instead of smooth transition from 5 to 1. Please note that I added time info node to evolution

[image]

enter image description here

[image: It moves at the speed of 5 first then I keyframed it from 5 to 1 where it acts abnormal and comes to the speed of 1 instead of smooth transition from 5 to 1. Please note that I added time info node to evolution.]

[image: This is the node tree]

Answer (score 3):

Don't keyframe Animation Nodes properties, instead, use an *Animate Node*:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: I am a beginner in animation nodes. Then where should I connect this green falloff node ? From which frame to which frame the animation will happen ?

Comment: @RafeequeBinUsman Don't use the Wiggle Falloff node, just use the Vector Falloff as you were using. The animation will start from frame zero, to start it from another frame, you can use the *Delay Time* node.